# Next Js & Typescript - Property setState does not exist on type Example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, next.js

Code works fine, but I can't figure out how to remove this error in VSCode.
Thanks for help.

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface State {
  text: string;
}
export default class Example extends React.Component<State> {
 state: State = {
    text: 'SOME TEXT'
}

private handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({text: 'New Text'}); //error: property setState does not exist on type Example
}

public render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <h2 onClick={this.handleChange}>{this.state.text}</h2>
        </div>
    )
 }
}
```

Comment: So even though it's giving you the error, setstate still works?

Answer (score 11):

First off, make sure you have the react type definitions installed:

```
npm install @types/react @types/react-dom
```

Secondly, the generic for state goes second, not first. The first one is for props.

```
export default class Example extends React.Component<{}, State> {
```

Look at the React type definitions to verify this (go to definition on `Component`). `<P, S>` means props, then state.

```
class Component<P, S> {
```

Comment: Solved It. With adding npm install @types/react @types/react-dom  Thanks Man.

Comment: This should be a green tick!

Answer (score 7):

I resolved the same issue in VSCode just by changing the version of typescript used
=> open command palette > "select typescript version" > "use workspace version"